# can't view html content when submit form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i'm was create a menu and Form in wordpress.

then, i was create form send email for my customer.
it's oke. 
**But my problems is :**

- I'm writing some thing in editor, add color, font size... for text, add images....
  But when echo the result after click submit button, it not show same as in the editor content,
  all html code was removed, (the heading form h1 -> h6 is keep).
  **I want the result of Echo was same as in the forms. (All html was keep)**

Help me to solve this problem, Please !

here is my code

```
<form method="post" id="kaka" name="form_send_mail">
<?php wp_editor('default text', 'idgiday', $settings = array(
        'drag_drop_upload'  => true,
        'editor_height'     => '300',
        'textarea_name'     => 'textarea_name_td'
    ) ); 
?> 

    <imput type="text"></imput>
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<?php 
    echo  @$_POST['textarea_name_td'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to get the output via editor ID which you have mentioned `idgiday` ,

```
echo $_REQUEST['idgiday'];
```

You can save the editor output via,

```
add_post_meta($post_id,'idgiday',$_REQUEST['idgiday']);
```

And then get the output,

```
get_post_meta($post_id,'idgiday',true);
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed Ginani.
I'm trying your code. but it's not show everything.

echo $_REQUEST['idgiday'];


only echo $_POST or $_REQUEST of  name 'textarea_name_td' 
the value of textarea was show..